# Clean, simple CSS styles for text and table-heavy sites

Tags: css

I just want some basic, clean-looking CSS styles to apply to a site of mine that's a web application with lots of forms and tables.

Anyone have a theme or a set of CSS or a site I can look at to find examples? Also would like some decent printable stylesheets.

Answer (score 6):

**It all depends how is structured your html**, to apply the right CSS style, the right colors and effect.
Try to look here for some [visual examples on this article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/08/13/top-10-css-table-designs/)
and here there is [the source file with the css and html](http://media.smashingmagazine.com/cdn_smash/images/express-css-table-design/express-css-table-design.zip)

About printing consider that **backgrounds are not printed** (colored backgrounds and image backgrounds) you should use the media print. [An interesting articles on how to setup your CSS Print to optimise the design of your website](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/)

If you need more specific technical help, look over [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com) for coding help, if instead you need a suggestions on colors or composition come back here, but at least post an image :)

Comment: backgrounds *can* be printed, but it's usually better to take people to a `print` page so they know what they're going to get.

Comment: Yes they can if you activate on your software to do it. Only that by standard is not activated and it is not printed. Only power use do that, no common users. And you have to consider the waste of colors in printing a background (worst case scenario in black)

Answer (score 3):

For the tables specifically, you could check out this site which has CSS for many, many table styles:

http://icant.co.uk/csstablegallery

Answer (score 0):

You should search for **CSS cheatsheets,** if you want to print.

If you want to style tables, Google "Fancy CSS tables" and youll get something like this posts:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp

lutrov (DOT) com/fancy-html-tables-with-css

They both have your answer.

Hope it helps.

Designer love.

Answer (score 0):

Check out BlueTrip - combines Blueprint, Tripoli, Hartija, 960.gs, and Elements:

http://bluetrip.org/

Here's a decent list of CSS frameworks:

http://www.webdesignbooth.com/10-promising-css-framework-that-worth-a-look/